# How to delete elements of a ComboViewer?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, swt, jface

I have created a ComboViewer that contains Project type objects. When I select a Project, the elements of the same composite as the ComboViewer one update their values with the selected Project ones. The problem comes when I try to delete one element of the combobox. I update the list I pass to the ComboViewer with the setInput method and I refresh it. After that, the addSelectionListener event that I have defined to manage when the user clicks an element of the combo automatically triggers and it detects that the element is null thowing a NullPointerException. How can I make to delete the empty space that the combo leaves when I delete an element and to take the next one?

**Code**

I have created an event to control when an element of the combobox is selected and to update the other elements of the composite:

```
        projectNameTextCombo.addSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener() {
            public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event) {
                IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) event
                        .getSelection();
                selectedProjectCombo = (Project) selection.getFirstElement(); 
                updateEditionElements(selectedProjectCombo);
            }
        });
```

I have given the option to delete ComboViewer element:

```
    Button deleteProjectConfigButton = new Button(pluginPathCreatedComposite, SWT.NONE);
    deleteProjectConfigButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            projectList.getProjectList().remove(selectedProjectCombo);
            projectNameTextCombo.refresh();
        }
```

The Project class code is the following:

```
public class Project {
    private String name;
    private String path;
    private Integer quantity;
    private List<ProjectDirectory> projectDirectoryList;

    //Constructor
    public Project(String name, String path, Integer quantity, List<ProjectDirectory> projectDirectoriesList) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.path = path;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.projectDirectoryList = projectDirectoriesList;
    }

    public Project() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    //Getters & setters
}
```

I have defined the ComboViewer label provider, the content provider and the setInput data:

```
    setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());

    setLabelProvider(new LabelProvider() {
        @Override
        public String getText(Object element) {
            if (element instanceof Project && element != null) {
                Project current = (Project) element;
                return current.getName();
            }
            return super.getText(element);
        }
    });
```

To populate the combobox I use this function:

```
private void populateCombo(){
    if(projectList != null){
        //Returns a Project list
        projectNameTextCombo.setInput(projectList.getProjectList());

        //The first time update other composite elements manually
        projectNameTextCombo.getCombo().select(0);
        selectedProjectCombo = (Project) projectNameTextCombo.getElementAt(0);
        updateEditionElements(selectedProjectCombo);
    }
}
```

And to update the other composite elements I use this function:

```
private void updateEditionElements(Project project){
    editProjectPathText.setText(project.getPath());
    projectCompositeViewer.getTable().setEnabled(true);
    projectCompositeViewer.setInput(project);
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used Greg´s advice to manage to delete the elements of my comboViewer.

**Code**

```
    projectNameTextCombo.addSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener() {
        public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event) {
            IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) event
                    .getSelection();
            selectedProjectCombo = (Project) selection.getFirstElement();
            if (selectedProjectCombo != null) {
                updateEditionElements(selectedProjectCombo);
            }
            else {
                // Select the 0 position element
                projectNameTextCombo.getCombo().select(0);
                //Get the 0 element project of the comboviewer
                selectedProjectCombo = (Project) projectNameTextCombo.getElementAt(0);
                //If it is not null, update composite labels, else show information label
                if(selectedProjectCombo != null){
                    updateEditionElements(selectedProjectCombo);
                }else{
                    projectCreatedComposite.setVisible(false);
                    projectNotCreatedComposite.setVisible(true);
                    st.topControl = projectNotCreatedComposite;
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

These lines in your selection listener are assuming that there is always a selection:

```
selectedProjectCombo = (Project) selection.getFirstElement(); 
updateEditionElements(selectedProjectCombo);
```

This is not the case. When you delete an entry the selection will be cleared and `getFirstElement` will return `null`, so you need to check that there actually is a selection:

```
selectedProjectCombo = (Project) selection.getFirstElement(); 
if (selectedProjectCombo != null) {
  updateEditionElements(selectedProjectCombo);
}
else {
  // TODO deal with empty selection
}
```